# Get word from array in word2vec in gensim

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I just started to experiment with word2vec form gensim using tutorial provide in [http://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/](http://radek'%20s%20tutorial). If we need need the raw output vectors, we write:

```
model['computer']
```

And the result is:

```
array([-0.00449447, -0.00310097,  0.02421786, ...], dtype=float32)
```

How can I get the word having the array? So if I write:

```
f=model['computer']
```

how can I get the word 'computer' using f?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from this site [https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/381](http://gensim):

```
word=model.most_similar(positive=[f],topn=1)
print(word[0][0])
```